# MS Access: Group by Another field in table

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, group-by, subquery

Using purely MS Access' Designer view, is it possible to output a query that displays the count of one column given the number/types of vales in another column?

For example, I have a table with RetailerID (consisting of unique values) and Group (values limited to ABC, DEF, GHI as group names). How do I give an output that counts the number of RetailerID in each Group?

Such as
ABC - 5
DEF - 10
GHI - 7

Comment: Sounds like a simple aggregate (GROUP BY) query. In query design view, click the Sigma symbol on the ribbon to switch to aggregate query mode.

Comment: I have tried making it work using SQL statements. Just asking if there's a way to do it in designer view by clicking and drag/drops so that other colleagues can attempt it!